# Sort by byte location

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, gnu, gnu-coreutils

I'm on a linux server using bash. I've some data that looks like

```
20130101 Z27
20170101 F40
20170501UZ24
20160701BA27
20120411 A27
20170101 Z30
```

And I am solely interested at sorting by byte location = 8-11. 
Is there a way for GNU `sort` to sort by this byte range?

I am looking for a similar option as to what `cut` has with `-b` where I can specify a byte range.

I can write a Python script to do this, but I'd rather keep everything on a simple bash script for others to read and follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$ sort -t $'\n' -k 1.8,1.11 infile
20120411 A27
20160701BA27
20170101 F40
20170501UZ24
20130101 Z27
20170101 Z30
```

`-t $'\n'` tells `sort` that the field separator is the newline character, i.e., every line consists of just one field.

`-k 1.8,1.11` says to use characters 8 to 11 within field 1 to sort by.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great solution.